# Does scala.collection.Seq.groupBy() function preserve the order?

Tags: scala, collections, seq

I'm trying to figure out:

1. If `scala.collection.Seq.groupBy()` preservers the order. Meaning if I have `List((true, 2), (true, 8))`, and do groupBy by the first element which is the boolean, will I always end up with a list for true which has 2 before 8.
2. Same question for toMap. Meaning if I do a toMap on the mentioned list, will I always end up having 8 for the key true, cause 8 comes after 2 and overrides it?

I could not find anything about the implementation in the scala doc: [scala doc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.collection.Seq). I'm trying to decide whether write my own version of it to make sure the order is preserved.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behavior is [documented](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-RC2/scala/collection/TraversableLike.html#groupBy[K]%28f:A=%3EK%29:scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]):

> A map from keys to traversable collections such that the following
>   invariant holds: `(xs groupBy f)(k) = xs filter (x => f(x) == k)`

means it's defined in terms of equals.

Filter specifies "The order of the elements is preserved."

Therefore, yes, ordering is preserved as specified.

Similarly, toMap says:

> Duplicate keys will be overwritten by later keys: if this is an
>   unordered collection, which key is in the resulting map is undefined.

That is, last key in ordered collection provides the value.